# Is it OK to use flutter_hydrated for splash screen and authentication? Flutter

Tags: json, flutter, bloc

When the user downloads the app and opens it for the first time, a splash screen should show telling him to log in or other stuff. Then, every time the user re-open the app it should check for if the user is authenticated or not.

Can I do this with `hydrated_bloc`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using `Firebase` backend then on each launch of the app you will call `firebaseInstance.currentUser()` to check if authorized or not and this check will be through an event from the `bloc` when the app launches

If you are not using this backend then also on each launch of the app you will call some method to check if auth token (if exists) is still valid also through an event from the `bloc`

Now the `HydratedBloc` can save the previous state of the app but suppose you save the previous state and the user doesn't open the app until after token expires and you are using `HydratedBloc` so you will only rely on it to check the previously saved state (auth status) and not use the methods above so in this case you will login an UNAUTHENTICATED user into the app.

And if you say I will also do the above methods then what is the point of using this `bloc` in this case?

So looks like it is an overkill to use this `bloc` for this feature

Comment: The point of doing this is to avoid the loading time of the `auth blocbuilder`. 
I'm using *Laravel* and *MySQL* for the backend and the app is an e-commerce store so it's ok to show the homepage for the user,  then check if the authentication token exists while he is scamming the app.
Should I do this with hydrated or not?

Comment: If as you are saying it is ok if he sees the homepage but he can't do any transactions unless he is logged in and you can make sure of that
then you can use the hydrated bloc or store a simple bool of last state in shared prefs if you want a shortet solution